# Putting the return of String.split(delimiter) into a String[]

Tags: java, arrays, string

I did read the documentaion on String.split(delimiter) and it says that the return type is String[]. But I don't know how to take that return of String.split() and assign its elements to my receiving String[].  The simple-minded

```
String[] z = stuff.split(" ");
```

(where stuff is a String) does not work. It compiles fine, but the z ends up being some mumbo-jumbo with ampersands. Looks like toString of something, not like a String array. Please enlighten me. Thanks.

UPADTE: Sorry for asking this. Of course it works. I knew too little at the time and was overwhelmed.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the original question. The corrected question is shown now. No, String[] z = stuff.split(" "); does not work. System.out.println(" z = "+z); gives z = [Ljava.lang.String;@18e2b22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course a String array contains a `toString` method witch is what was probably called ...

From the comments by the OP:

> Sorry, I made a mistake in the original question. The corrected question is shown now. No, `String[] z = stuff.split(" ");` does not work. `System.out.println(" z = "+z);` gives `z = [Ljava.lang.String;@18e2b22`

You should try this to print out the String array correctly:

```
String[] z = stuff.split(" ");
System.out.println("z = " + Arrays.toString(z));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the length of the of the returned array cannot be stuff.length() but count of the stuff portions delimited by given delimiter. It doesn't matter anyway because your initialized array will be discarded after assignment of new value returned by the split function. Find your string portions in z[i] strings where i < z.length ( or z.size() ).